# Error when displaying PDF in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, itext

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app that return dynamic PDF for client to display. The PDF was generated by iTextSharp, and binary data will return to client as 'application/pdf'.
When I deploy the app on server, everything works fine.
But when I deploy on localhost IIS (desktop), sometimes it worked but many times it didn't.
I tested by click on the same link to return the same PDF and sometimes Chrome display it correctly (in another tab) but many times Chrome will force download the pdf but the download processing never end.
I have removed all the antivirus & suspested software that i think it will affect the pdf return but the problem still happens.
Does anyone experience the same problem & please give me some advices to try?
Thanks.
MillDol

Comment: What about other browsers? Do you see the same behavior there? If not, that excludes iTextSharp from the equation, and we know that it's a pure Chrome problem.

Comment: Also, before sending the PDF to the client, try writing the PDF to disk first and then transmitting it. Although it is convenient to write directly to the `Response.OutputStream`, seeing the raw bytes on the server before sending to the client is so much easier to debug.